# How does an android app fit in all different APIs?

Tags: android, api

When you download an APP, the layout was fine regardless of what API the phone has. When I was making an APP for a school project, I used a different API to what my phone has in development , the layout was so messed up. Does the programmer release different versions for different APIs and when you download the APK, the app store determines which API you have and provides you with the corresponding version?

Comment: You need to read some documentation about android development basics, also there are hundreds of tutorials on youtube about layout designs

Answer (score 1):

> "When I was making an APP for a school course last semester, I used a
>   different API to what my phone has in development , the layout was so
>   messed up."

even the apk is compiled against certain api version the difference could be a result of:

1. implementation eg of components per os version (the implementation on device is different than the one the developer has compiled the app against)
2. mixing and usage of different support library version the app is compiled against - to maintain compatibility developer could use a support library or newest framework called androidx
3. each vendor/oem (original equipment manufacture) may alter the aosp but it need to maintain CDD [difference for altered framework / res / theming - vary by device oem] eg. deprecated overlays
4. usage of JIT
5. result of bugs
6. constantly changing android/gradle build tools altering the result of newly compiled the same source code of apk
7. the dev could use a custom class loader which may produce a different result each time the app is launched - eg like google uses its own network class loader in the account manager to create on device google accounts
8. the app could be an instant app or module app

mostly is a result of theming [styleables, attributes, even produced by os drawables]

for more info please refer to:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/
https://source.android.com/compatibility/overview
https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/

> "Does the programmer release different versions for different APIs and
>   when you download the APK, the app store determines which API you have
>   and provides you with the corresponding version?"

**MOSTLY NO but the dev could make per configuration or architecture apk's so the play store could serve different one based on device type**

see:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility#version):

"Platform version
Different devices may run different versions of the Android platform, such as Android 4.0 or Android 4.4. Each successive platform version often adds new APIs not available in the previous version. To indicate which set of APIs are available, each platform version specifies an API level. For instance, Android 1.0 is API level 1 and Android 4.4 is API level 19.

The API level allows you to declare the minimum version with which your app is compatible, using the  manifest tag and its minSdkVersion attribute. For example, the Calendar Provider APIs were added in Android 4.0 (API level 14). If your app cannot function without these APIs, you should declare API level 14 as your app's minimum supported version.

**The minSdkVersion attribute declares the minimum version with which your app is compatible and the targetSdkVersion attribute declares the highest version on which you've optimized your app**"

In your `build.gradle (Module: app)` file you always have something like:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.myapp'

    // Defines the minimum API level required to run the app.
    minSdkVersion 15

    // Specifies the API level used to test the app.
    targetSdkVersion 28

    ...
  }
}
```

"**Each successive version of Android provides compatibility for apps that were built using the APIs from previous platform versions**, so your app should always be compatible with future versions of Android while using the documented Android APIs"

I think it is also very nice the note in the same link:

> Note: The targetSdkVersion attribute does not prevent your app from
> being installed on platform versions that are higher than the
> specified value, but it is important because it indicates to the
> system whether your app should inherit behavior changes in newer
> versions. **If you don't update the targetSdkVersion to the latest
> version, the system assumes that your app requires some
> backward-compatibility behaviors when running on the latest version.**
> For example, among the behavior changes in Android 4.4, alarms created
> with the AlarmManager APIs are now inexact by default so the system
> can batch app alarms and preserve system power, but the system will
> retain the previous API behavior for your app if your target API level
> is lower than "19"

More details on the setup of the Android Support Libraries needed to guarantee the Backward Compatibility for newer APIs can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)

With regard to fixing the `minSdkVersion` the documentation comes to help again:

"If your app uses APIs added in a more recent platform version, but does not require them for its primary functionality, you should check the API level at runtime and gracefully degrade the corresponding features when the API level is too low. In this case, **set the minSdkVersion to the lowest value possible for your app's primary functionality**, then compare the current system's version, SDK_INT, to one the codename constants in Build.VERSION_CODES that corresponds to the API level you want to check. For example:"

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // Running on something older than API level 11, so disable
    // the drag/drop features that use <code><a href="/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html">ClipboardManager</a></code> APIs
    disableDragAndDrop();
}
```

---

Another very important point that not reported yet in that link is that "Starting on the dates listed below, the Play Console will require that APK uploads target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26)" [source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk)

[image: Google new requirements]

so to be compliant you have to set up the preceding `build.gradle` file with nothing less than:

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

This one is [another very good link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) that tells more about the "Google Play's target API level requirement", outlining all the suggestions to update your app

Finally, if you can't manage to deploy the app with a single apk [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api) provides you directions to "Create multiple APKs for different API levels". Please note that in the same link they do NOT recommend this solution, unless strictly necessary

It may seem at the outset as though multiple APK support is the best solution, but this often isn’t the case

Answer (score 0):

The same version of APK is used for every versions of android supported by the app. The fact that the app looks identical across different versions of Android is most of the time due to the usage of Android Support Libraries (or android x).
Nevertheless, with the new Android Bundles , the developer can define portions of the app which are available only to specific versions of Android.